# Carbon isn't giving the correct datetime with setTimezone

Tags: laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I'm using Carbon inside of my Laravel API project, when trying to set the timezone and get a datetime back in the user's timezone, I'm for some reason getting a UTC value back, what am I doing wrong?

```php
// $user->timezone will give me "America/Curacao" or whatever their time zone is
$curr = Carbon::now()->setTimezone($user->timezone)
```

But when I echo out the contents of `$curr`, I'm getting a UTC time of:

> 2021-04-05T11:58:35.186750Z

What am I missing?

Comment: If you on **Laravel 7** or above version, then your api will provide the UTC based time

Comment: Why would it do that when I'm explicitly setting my timezone with `setTimezone`?

Comment: Do you have the same result with `Carbon::now(new \DateTimeZone($user->timezone);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You get the ISO-8601 string with is the standard format for dates in JSON. But the object is correctly in `America/Curacao` timezone. If you want to pass it to a `Date` object in the browser, you don't need the timezone and can just pass this string as is.

If you want to format the date to be seen by the user, then just pick the format after setting the timezone:

```
$curr = Carbon::now()->setTimezone($user->timezone)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Or whatever format would be relevant for you.

And you should keep `'timezone' => 'UTC'` in your app settings as your users will likely have any various timezone, and UTC is the more agnostic to use to save them back-end side.